# Unexpected behavior with dplyr group_by followed by factor in mutate

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

In the data.frame at the bottom of this question, I want to compute the number of individuals by year and age, create a year-class variable that is the year minus the age, and then create factor versions of the age and year-class variables.  Using `group_by()`, `summarize()`, and `mutate()` from `dplyr` and `factor()` from `base` R I get the following result:

```
d <- group_by(d,year,age) %>% summarize(catch=n())
d1 <- mutate(d,yrclass=year-age,fage=as.factor(age),fyrclass=as.factor(yrclass))
d1

Source: local data frame [27 x 6]
Groups: year

   year age catch yrclass fage fyrclass
1  2010   3    13    2007    3     2007
2  2010   4    10    2006    4     2006
3  2010   5    19    2005    5     2005
4  2010   6    24    2004    6     2004
5  2010   7    19    2003    7     2003
6  2010   8    32    2002    8     2002
7  2010   9    22    2001    9     2001
8  2010  10    13    2000   10     2000
9  2011   2     5    2009    3       NA
10 2011   3     9    2008    4       NA
..  ... ...   ...     ...  ...      ...
```

One can see in rows 9 and 10 that the factored versions of "age" and "yrclass" are not correct.

However, if I strip the non-data.frame classes (i.e., remove the dplyr related classes) from my d data.frame then these errors disappear.

```
d <- as.data.frame(d)
d2 <- mutate(d,yrclass=year-age,fage=as.factor(age),fyrclass=as.factor(yrclass))
d2  # only first 10 rows shown

   year age catch yrclass fage fyrclass
1  2010   3    13    2007    3     2007
2  2010   4    10    2006    4     2006
3  2010   5    19    2005    5     2005
4  2010   6    24    2004    6     2004
5  2010   7    19    2003    7     2003
6  2010   8    32    2002    8     2002
7  2010   9    22    2001    9     2001
8  2010  10    13    2000   10     2000
9  2011   2     5    2009    2     2009
10 2011   3     9    2008    3     2008
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

The data are below (from dput).  I attempted to make a smaller reproducible example but I could not determine a pattern that resulted in the same errors.

```
d <- structure(list(year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L), age = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 12L)),
.Names = c("year","age"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -436L))
```

Comment: You can compress the repetitions in that code with `c(rep(2010,136), rep(2011,152), ...)`

Comment: In fact just do `rle(...)`. You get `Run Length Encoding  lengths: int [1:...] 136 152 ... values : num [1:...] 2010 2011 ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works correctly if you add the missing trailing `%>% ungroup()` ; you were skipping the Combine step in Split-Apply-Combine.
I don't know that it is even defined behavior to try to operate on the `grouped_df`, rather than the dataframe.

```
d <- group_by(d,year,age) %>% summarize(catch=n()) %>% ungroup()

mutate(d,yrclass=year-age,fage=as.factor(age),fyrclass=as.factor(yrclass))
Source: local data frame [27 x 6]

   year age catch yrclass fage fyrclass
1  2010   3     1    2007    3     2007
2  2010   4     1    2006    4     2006
3  2010   5     1    2005    5     2005
4  2010   6     1    2004    6     2004
5  2010   7     1    2003    7     2003
6  2010   8     1    2002    8     2002
7  2010   9     1    2001    9     2001
8  2010  10     1    2000   10     2000
9  2011   2     1    2009    2     2009
10 2011   3     1    2008    3     2008
..  ... ...   ...     ...  ...      ...
```

And by the way **you can compress your testcase** (using `rle`) to get:

```
d <- data.frame(year = c(rep(2010,152), rep(2011,136),rep(2012,148)),
     age =  c(rep(3,13), rep(4,10), rep(5,19), rep(6,24), rep(7,19),
            rep(8,32), rep(9,22),  rep(10,13), rep(2,5), rep(3,9),
            rep(4,11), rep(5,13), rep(6,19), rep(7,12),  rep(8,17),
            rep(9,28), rep(10,11), rep(11,11), rep(3,26), rep(4,47),
            rep(5,23), rep(6,13), rep(7,11), rep(8,7), rep(9,9),
            rep(10,10), rep(12,2)) )

>which we got from
> rr <- rle(d$age)
> print(paste('rep(', unlist(as.list(paste(rr$values, rr$lengths, sep=','))) , '),', sep='' ), quote=F)
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply.  The use of `ungroup` does solve the problem, as did my use of `as.data.frame`.  Your answer also suggests that you view this as a bug.  So, is this a bug, or is it intended that `ungroup` be used?  How do I explain to others why `ungroup` is necessary here.

Comment: Thank you also for `rle`.  This was new to me.

Comment: I edited my answer to be clearer: probably what you were doing was wrong (skipping the ungroup step), and I don't know that it is even defined behavior to try to operate on the `grouped_df`, rather than the dataframe.